# How to working with treepicker in extjs 4.1.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I try to create treepicker but i can't done with that **http://jsfiddle.net/UKFVd/**

Here is my code

```
var Panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        bodyPadding: 5, 
        width: 300,
        height: 100,
        title: 'Filters',
        items: [ {
            xtype: 'treepicker',
            name: 'list_id',
            fieldLabel: 'Task List',
            labelWidth: 60,
            displayField: 'text',
            store: store
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

i check error is `TypeError: k is undefined` How to working with treepicker thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to include:

```
Ext.ux.TreePicker
```

if you have not.

The code in the fiddle you posted is perfectly fine, however, on the left side under External Resources, add the full URL path to TreePicker.js, and try again, and it will work.

Here is a working fiddle rev: http://jsfiddle.net/UKFVd/6/

Comment: The fiddle does not seem to work anymore (TreePicker not found), but the advice is still valid for up until Ext 6 even.

Answer (score 0):

Tree picker is not an out of box component that ships with extjs, you have to add it to your web page as an additional resource.
here is a page showing examples:
http://extjs.dariofilkovic.com/

Comment: The OP is using treepicker, not treecombo (which is what the URL you suggested is using). They are different. Treepicker actually ships with extjs (at least in 4.2.1) as a ux, but treecombo does not.